# null reference exception in app.UseExceptionHandler in startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

ASP.NET Core 5 Web API and in `startup` class, I use this method for global exception handling.

I want to log exception into the database.

```
    app.UseExceptionHandler(a => a.Run(async context =>
            {
                var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
                var exception = exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error;
                
                //  For Save Exception Log
                if(exception != null)
                {
                    exceptionLogger.AddException(exception);
                }

                // For Show Json Error in Resoponse
                await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new DTOResultObject(exception.Message));
            }));
```

my Exception logger class is:

```
 public  class ExceptionLogger : BaseService<ExceptionLog>, IExceptionService
    {

        protected IBaseRepository<ExceptionLog> _TRepository;
       
        public ExceptionLogger(IBaseRepository<ExceptionLog> TRepository) : base(TRepository)
        {
            _TRepository = (IBaseRepository<ExceptionLog>)TRepository;
        }
        

        public async Task addAddException(ExceptionLog exception)
        {
            //    mongo.insert<ExceptionLog>(document);
            await _TRepository.Insert(exception);
            await _TRepository.Save();
        }
        public async Task AddException(System.Exception exception1)
        {
            try
            {
                await addAddException(new ExceptionLog()
                {
                    exception = exception1,
                    date = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Utc),
                    message = exception1.Message,
                    stackTrace = exception1.StackTrace
                });
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
               await addAddException(new ExceptionLog()
                {
                    exception = ex,
                    date = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Utc),
                    message = ex.Message,
                    stackTrace = ex.StackTrace
                });
            }
        }
```

and my exception log class :

```
 public class ExceptionLog : IEntity
    {
        //public ObjectId id { get; set; }
        //[JsonIgnore]
        public Exception exception { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string stackTrace { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to log exception into database, the exception is not null and it goes to the if() loop, but unfortunately it throws a null reference exception for the exception variable in the `AddException` method.

Could you please help me with this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is the `exceptionLogger` null?

Comment: It's a property from exceptionLogger class that contains AddException method and it's null

Comment: Could you post your exceptionLogger class code? What is the AddException method?

Comment: I edit the question as you said

Answer (score -1):

Based on the code you provided, it seems that the issue might be with the `exceptionLogger` object or the `AddException` method itself. It's possible that the `exceptionLogger` object is null, or the `AddException` method is not handling the null exception parameter properly.

Hope it' Help

Comment: This issue is for exceptionLogger that is a property and the error says that it is null